# Illustrator CS6 white lines showing in repeat

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I've tried everything.Preferences- general-anti aliased artwork makes design look fine.Upload or check it in photoshop and the line is still there.A months work of work messed up.
My thinking is I have something selected or checked somewhere and it's screwing up my work.

[image]

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.The white lines I am referring to are different that the white horizontal lines the other user asked about.